# Error: Connection timeout at SMTPConnection._formatError

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, email

Error: Connection timeout  at SMTPConnection._formatError, don't know what is wrong, can't send mails,please help me.
am trying to send a mail using nodemailer, but i keep getting this error in my console

```
    Error: Connection timeout
        at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/codabae/Desktop/mailmonster/Backend/v1/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
        at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
        at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      command: 'CONN'
    }
```

this is my api
here i don't know what am doing wrong, i getting the details from the mongodb and am filling it in the nodmailer fields, i really don't know what am doing wrong.

```
    router.post('/', auth, (req, res) => {
    const { to, cc, bcc, subject, message, attachment, smtpDetails } = req.body;

    if (!to || !subject || !message || !smtpDetails) return res.status(400).send('input cannot be empty')

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '...@gmail.com',
            pass: '...'
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from:  '...@gmail.com',
        to: to,
        cc: cc,
        bcc: bcc,
        subject: subject,
        text: `${message}`
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.send('mail not sent')

        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            res.send('mail sent')
        }
    });    

    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this - I am stuck at the same issue

Comment: check if your wifi provider has allowed access to the smtp servers. in my case my college wifi blocked the request, i tried my phone hotspot it worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The part of the error message to focus on here is `SMTPConnection._formatError`. You are receiving this error because the transport configuration variables are not correct. You need the following variables, with correct values for each.

There are additional variables that can be used, but based on the fields in your code, the following configuration should work fine. If you need additional info, you can always reference the [Nodemailer documentation](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/).

```
//transport configuration for user a site server to send an email.
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    // This is the SMTP mail server to use for notifications. 
    // GCDS uses this mail server as a relay host.
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    // SMTP is unlike most network protocols, which only have a single port number. 
    // SMTP has at least 3. They are port numbers 25, 587, and 465.
    // Port 25 is still widely used as a **relay** port from one server to another.
    // Port for SSL: 465
    // Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
    port: 465,
    //  if true the connection will use TLS when connecting to server. If false (the 
    // default) then TLS is used if server supports the STARTTLS extension. In most 
    // cases set this value to true if you are connecting to port 465. For port 587 or 
    // 25 keep it false
    secure: true, // use TLS
    auth: {
        // Your full email address
        user: process.env.SMTP_TO_EMAIL,
        // Your Gmail password or App Password
        pass: process.env.SMTP_TO_PASSWORD
    }
});
```

You mentioned filling these in using some sort of information from MongoDB. I cannot see from where you are getting the variables and values in your configuration, but you may need to use a different source or update your query if you are pulling the values from a database.

*NOTE:*
Another common issue to be aware of involves using the Gmail password, which **cannot** be used if your account has 2FA enabled. In this case you must generate a unique App Password by following [these guidelines](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) from Google.